# Issues with kallah trying on wedding ring before wedding

Tags: transactions, wedding, kiddushin-eirusin

Does the kallah trying on a wedding ring for size before the actual wedding cause a problem of her having taken possession of the ring before the wedding?

Comment: Is she trying to take possession of it before the wedding?

Comment: Does trying on clothing at a store force you to pay for the item?

Comment: Even if she had intent to acquire it would not be enough unless the chasson also had intent to give it to her at that time.

Comment: @Ariel Also she could just give it back to to the groom even if she did acquire it.